# pyenchant for other languages

Tags: python-3.x, pyenchant

I know this was a topic before but unfortunately, nothing is working when it comes to the old solutions. So I need to figure out how to use pyenchant for german.
If I use enchant.list_languages() it just shows me all kinds of English languages.

Edit: I'm using windows

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer using python 3.10 and windows 11.
Download both `.aff` and `.dic` files from:
https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries

Then copy the files to the folder `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\enchant\data\mingw64\share\enchant\hunspell`

If you're using other Linux, Mac, or your Windows configuration is different, type `pip show pyenchant` in terminal to see where `pyenchant` is installed, then navigate to subfolder `enchant\data\mingw64\share\enchant\hunspell` to find the dictionaries folder.